# Берсерк или берсеркер?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Встречала в литературе оба варианта написания. А как все-таки правильно называется воин, впадающий в подобное состояние: берсерк или берсеркер?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чаще "берсерк" называют, "берсеркер" тоже ошибкой не будет. Оригинальное название, среднее между ними, - berserkr.

Comment: Марк Из, Вы, боюсь, путаете.  
berserkr - это множественное число. Единственное - berserk.

Comment: @behemothus, нет, ничего не путаю. Скандинавский вариант с "r", который обозначает именительный падеж, единственное число. 
В английском из этого слова получилоссь berserk, а в немецком - berserker. В словарях присутствуют оба варианта, у Брокгауза-Ефрона и Чудинова - "берсеркер". В белорусском "Средневековый мир в терминах, именах и названиях" - берсерк. Встроенный автокорректор подчёркивает последний вариант.

Comment: А каков перевод слова? "Бер" - медведь? "Медведеборец", "подобный медведю"?

Comment: @ихарка, по старонорвежски   berserkr означает либо «медвежья шкура» либо «без рубашки» (корень ber- может означать как «медведь», так и «голый»; -serkr означает «шкура», «шёлк» (ткань)